# Javascript/PHP re-populate dropdown on form submission fails

Tags: php, javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am using so javascript to load different forms based on a drop down selection like below:

```
<select id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
<option value = "0">Select Option</option>
<option value = "1">Option 1</option>
<option value = "2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id = "f1" style="display:none">
<form name= "form1">
Content of Form 1
</form>
</div>

<div id = "f2" style="display:none">
<form name= "form2">
Content of Form 2
</form>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function showForm(){
var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
if (selopt == 1) {
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
}
if (selopt == 2) {
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
}
}

</script>
```

I have removed the actually form details because they dont matter at this point. Anyways, when the form is submitted it passes a series of validations:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
 //validation codes

}
```

This works great, but if the validation fails it reloads the page and therefore resets the dropdown box, and doesn't show the previously selected option. I want it to keep the previous selection, or just to have for example load selection 1 into the javascript bit when the submission fails. any ideas?

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this at the end of your javascript if validation fails

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("opts").value = <?php echo $_POST['opts']; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Why at the end of the JavaScript? It should just be on the page, preferably in the head.

Comment: thankyou. I did somethign very similar after the validation where it reloads option one and on the validation for form 2 reloads option 2.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? This one here does not show/hide the tags you have in your function unless the options CHANGE. Mine will show/hide regardless

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("opts").onchange=function() {
    var selopt = this.value;
    document.getElementById("f1").style.display=(selopt==1)?"block":"none";
    document.getElementById("f2").style.display=(selopt==2)?"block":"none";
  }
  document.getElementById("opts").onchange(); // show/hide when reloaded
}
```

using this PHP which will set the select to whatever it was when submitted

```
<? $sel = $_POST['opts']; ?>
<select name="opts" id ="opts">
<option value = "0"<? if ($sel==0) echo " selected ";?>>Select Option</option>
<option value = "1"<? if ($sel==1) echo " selected ";?>>Option 1</option>
<option value = "2"<? if ($sel==2) echo " selected ";?>>Option 2</option>
</select>
```